# use css3 to add display:block but with a delay

Tags: css, sass

Wondering if there is a way to add `display:block;` inline, **but with a small 3 second delay... without JS, and with CSS(3) inline with styles**

```
.janet-place{
    $width: 138;
    $height: 452;
    width: rcalc($width);
    margin-left: rcalc(50);
    margin-top:rcalc(31);
    padding:hcalc($height,$width)  0;
    display: block; // here after 3 seconds
    @include bkgrd_image('animation/gown.png');
    &.gown{ display: block; // here after 3 more seconds}
    &.janet{ background-image: url("../images/animation/janet.png");}
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Not really, as `display` is not a transitionable property, but there are alternatives. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass?  Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled CSS.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use css animation http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp It is the only time sensitive css I am aware of.

animation-fill-mode may help;   Specifies a style for the element when the animation is not playing (when it is finished, or when it has a delay)

Answer (score -1):

Try to adjust this code accordingly

```css
.janet-place{
    $width: 138;
    $height: 452;
    width: rcalc($width);
    margin-left: rcalc(50);
    margin-top:rcalc(31);
    padding:hcalc($height,$width)  0;
    display: inline; // here after 3 seconds
    @include bkgrd_image('animation/gown.png');
    &.gown{ display: block; // here after 3 more seconds}
    &.janet{ background-image: url("../images/animation/janet.png");}
    background-size: 100%;

    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}


/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {display: inline;}
    to {display: block;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    from {display: inline;}
    to {display: block;}
}
```